# What's the simplest way to replicate a HTML table in android?

Tags: android

I am building a website scraper and I want to replicate a HTML table in an android activity.

Is there a simple way of doing it with the table html rather than building it row by row..?

-i am using jsoup for parsing the html

Comment: Could you just display the table html in a webview?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Display the html in a WebView.